# For loop returns last item not iterating

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to print an array of objects on a JavaFX panel which I created.

When I iterate like this:

```
Product[] arr = new Product[2];
arr[0] = new Food("Apple", 3.44, "fruit", false);
arr[1] = new Food("Orange", 3.14, "fruit", false);

for (int i= 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Label label = new Label(arr[i].name);
    label.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    productGridPane.add(label, 0, 0);
}
```

it only returns the last item ( orange ) name.

Comment: you have no return statement in your code.

Comment: What’s the “0, 0” there? Are you overwriting the same grid cell on each iteration?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As it is, we don't know what a `productGridPane` is.  What are the parameters of `productGridPane` doing?  It's possible your `label` is overwriting the previous `label`, but without seeing what's happening it's impossible to know more.

Comment: Why is this question tagged "Spring"?

Comment: Removed "spring" tag as the accepted answer (and code in the question) is JavaFX code only with no "spring" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@skidwiz is right. We are unaware of what `productGridPane` is. It is likely an instance of the JavaFX GridPane Class.

If so, take a look at [JavaFX 8 GridPane Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

In your call of the `add()` method you are adding each node (label) to the column-index of 0 and row-index of 0.

This is just going to "stack" the nodes on top of each other. The last node you add will be the highest on this stack because it has the highest z-order.

If you look at your second and third parameters, you'll see that both the second parameter (column index) and third parameter (row index) are set to 0.

So, since you are looping the entire `arr` array and adding the label to the `productGridPane`, you keep "stacking" that value because it has the same coordinates as the other nodes in the `GridPane`, thus the last item in the array will be "highest on the stack", meaning it is the value you see. In this case the last value is the item with the name "Orange".

Depending on how you want your `GridPane` to appear, the solution may vary.

You likely want to change at least 1, but possibly (not likely) both parameters describing the column-index and row-index.

**Solution 1)**
Changing the column index to your loop counter variable `i` will add items along the columns (left to right):

```
productGridPane.add(label, i, 0);
```

**Solution 2)**
Changing the row index to your loop counter variable `i` will add items along the rows (top to bottom):

```
productGridPane.add(label, 0, i);
```

**Uncommon Solution 3)**
Changing both the column and row index to your loop counter variable `i` will add items by increasing both the column and row index. Highly unlikely you would do this. Consider the first two options as a solution.

```
productGridPane.add(label, i, i);
```

Comment: *"you keep overwriting that value because it is in the "same spot "in the GridPane, thus the last item in the array will be the value you see"*. But this isn't actually the behavior of a `GridPane`. If you add two nodes and give them  the same grid coordinates, they will both appear in the grid pane, on top of each other, with the last one having the higher z-order. Since `Label`, by default, has a transparent background, you would see both labels in this scenario (albeit with the text difficult to decipher).

Comment: @James_D thanks for the clarification. I have made edits to my answer that incorporates your corrections.